# Start activity after Resume

Tags: android

My start activity is a `LoginView`. 
If the login was correct i call `startActivity(new Intent(LoginView.this, MainView.class));` and `finish()`.

So my App switch to the `MainView` and if i press the back button the app goes to the backgroud.

My Problem:

If i resume the app (long press the home key) i always come back to the `LoginView` and not to the `Mainview`

MainView:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String name=username.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("username", name);
            if(name.equals("xxx"))
                {

                    Intent intent=new Intent(currentactivity.this,nextactivity.class);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
                }   
        }
    });
```